# How do I grep out of every tar archive on a system using 'find' and -exec 'tar'?

Tags: linux, find, tar

The command I'm trying (as I'm trying to find tars with 'butterflyinmotion.com' as a dir in them) is:

```
find / -name "*.tar.gz" -exec tar -tzf {} \; | grep -W butterflyinmotion
```

This shows a lot of errors and isn't working. The grep -W is necessary so I know what file the butterflyinmotion.com backup is in. Thanks!

Comment: If you are using gnu grep, then there is no -W option which is at least one of the reasons that you are receiving errors. If you just want the filename that the string appears in, use the -l option. If you want both the string and the filename, use the  -H option.Lastly, add the expected output to your question.

Comment: There is an option to show filenames (either -l or -L) for grep, but that work because all grep see is a stream of lines.

Comment: It may be a good idea to add `2> /dev/null` between `\;` and `| grep`, to remove all those "access denied" errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to make a little script, and call it with `find -exec`.

For example:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo ">>> $1"
tar tvf "$1"
```

call it with -exec ./script.sh "{}" \; and redirect the result to file, then grep the file `egrep '>>>|WhatYouLookFor' file`

You could also grep in the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo ">>> $1"
tar tvf "$1" | grep 'WhatYouLookFor'
```

Or more flexible:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo ">>> $2"
tar tvf "$2" | grep "$1"
```

call it with -exec ./script.sh 'WhatYouLookFor' "{}" \;

Answer (score 0):

At least with GNU grep, you could do something like this:

```
find / -name '*.tar.gz' -exec sh -c '
  for t; do 
    tar -tvf "$t" | grep -m1 -l --label="$t" "butterflyinmotion"
  done
' {} + 2>/dev/null
```

This will output the names of the `.tar.gz` files whose archives contain at least one match of the pattern `butterflyinmotion`

---

With GNU tar, it appears to be possible (at least for simple patterns) to omit the grep and use the exit status of `tar -tf` directly ex.

```
find / -name '*.tar.gz' -exec tar --wildcards -tf {} '*butterflyinmotion' \; -print 2>/dev/null
```

The above will print the matching files (if any) followed by the name of the archive.